# throw if operator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What would be a more elegant way to rewrite the below code in kotlin.

```
if (xList.isEmpty()) {
   throw SomeException("xList was empty")
}
```

Do we have a throwif operator or something?

Comment: I assume you want to continue doing some stuff after that, so why not using a more functional style with a `when` with all your validations before the actual implementation? `when{xList.isEmpty() -> throw SomeException("..."); else -> /*your other stuff*/ }`. So it's just one expression

Comment: I don't believe there's a more elegant way to do that in your case. Another thing would be to check nullability of a property, in which case I'd use the elvis operator `?: throw SomeException(...)`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/assert.html

Answer (score 36):

I like to use the [`takeIf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) standard function to validate, with [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) addition, it gives this:

```
xList.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() } ?: throw SomeException("xList was empty")
```

---

I have to add that in most cases an `IllegalArgumentException` is what I need, and it is simpler to just use [`require`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html).
In cases that we need an `IllegalStateException`, we can rather use [`check`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html).

See also: [checkNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check-not-null.html), [requireNotNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html), [error](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/error.html)

Comment: Thanks! and also, 
`xList.takeUnless{ it.isEmpty() } ?: throw SomeException("xList was empty")`

Comment: I like this approach more than others based on OP question, just because is oneliner and you can add the exception

Comment: dustinevan , if you need to do something when empty you can simply use xList.ifEmpty { throw SomeException("xList was empty") }

Comment: This is so much less readable and more obtuse than the original code.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another suggestion, terse and not requiring additional code :

```
xList.isNotEmpty() || throw SomeException("xList was empty")
```

It works because `throw` is an expression, having the type `Nothing` which is a subtype of everything, including `Boolean`.

Comment: It works and is more concise, but it is non-idiomatic and less readable than the OP's original code.

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin library, there are functions which throw exception if the input is invalid, e.g.
 [`requireNotNull(T?, () -> Any)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require-not-null.html). You can refer to these functions and write a similar function to handle empty list if you want.

```
public inline fun <T> requireNotEmpty(value: List<T>?, lazyMessage: () -> Any): List<T> {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        val message = lazyMessage()
        throw IllegalArgumentException(message.toString())
    } else {
        return value
    }
}

//Usage:
requireNotEmpty(xList) { "xList was empty" }
```

Or simply use [`require(Boolean, () -> Any)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html):

```
require(!xList.isEmpty()) { "xList was empty" }
```

Comment: You can also use: require(xList.isNotEmpty()) { "xList was empty" }

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a function in the standard library, but you can easily do this yourself:

```
/**
 * Generic function, evaluates [thr] and throws the exception returned by it only if [condition] is true
 */
inline fun throwIf(condition: Boolean, thr: () -> Throwable) {
    if(condition) {
        throw thr()
    }
}

/**
 * Throws [IllegalArgumentException] if this list is empty, otherwise returns this list.
 */
fun <T> List<T>.requireNotEmpty(message: String = "List was empty"): List<T> {
    throwIf(this.isEmpty()) { IllegalArgumentException(message) }
    return this
}

// Usage
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list: List<Int> = TODO()
    list.filter { it > 3 }
        .requireNotEmpty()
        .forEach(::println)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original code is compact, transparent and flexible.
An extension `fun` with fixed exception may be more compact.

```
infix fun String.throwIf(b: Boolean) {
    if (b) throw SomeException(this)
}

"xList was empty" throwIf xList.isEmpty()
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and current solution is to use `ifEmpty`:

```
return xList.ifEmpty { throw SomeException("xList was empty") }
```