# What is this double pipe operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I found this code in a Kotlin library and I couldn't find any information on it.

```
open fun <Type : ScreenType> addScreen(type: Class<Type>, screen: Type) {
    !screens.containsKey(type) || throw GdxRuntimeException("Screen already 
    registered to type: $type.")
    screens.put(type, screen)
}
```

I don't understand the middle part. What is that strange "OR" operator doing there?

Comment: It's just a use of an "or" operator. Means the same as `if (screens.containsKey(type)) { throw GdxRuntimeException("Screen already registered to type: $type.") }`

Comment: @milleniumbug okay thank you. But why is then ```true || println("It works!")``` not compiling?

Comment: It is shown in use in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222982/throw-if-operator-in-kotlin. I don't like it but it will work because of `throw`. It is not a general case. ;-/

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library is this? Something with utilities for LibGDX?

Comment: @Tenfour04 exactly, it's from the ```ktx``` library. It's a Kotlin extension for LibGDX. https://github.com/libktx/ktx

Comment: [I found it.](https://github.com/libktx/ktx/blob/8c852074f917d4869bd8c3ca61dc3e87bb763db2/app/src/main/kotlin/ktx/app/game.kt#L94) I'm quite familiar with the library and I'm surprised to see such an ugly piece of code in it, because most of it is quite elegant.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeah I was also quite surprised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin, throwing an Exception evaluates as an expression that returns `Nothing`. Nothing is treated like a sub-type of anything else, so that first line of code is basically an expression of type `Boolean || Nothing`, which can be simplified to just `Boolean`. Kotlin also allows a line of code to simply be an expression (many other languages like Java do not), so you can simply put this line of code to evaluate the two parts of the expression sequentially, and the throw will be skipped (short-circuited) if the first part of the expression is true.

While writing code like this in Kotlin is *possible*, it is certainly not idiomatic. In my opinion, it is unclear for readability. The equivalent behavior can be achieved with code that very clearly shows its intent:

```
if (screens.containsKey(type)) {
    throw GdxRuntimeException("Screen already registered to type: $type.")
}
```

Comment: So that's why! So I can't put just a regular function in there because the function returns ```Unit``` and not ```Nothing```. So the expression ```Boolean || Unit``` is invalid and it doesn't work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Or if you don't need the specialised exception type, calling [`require()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/require.html) or [`check()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/check.html) is simpler and more idiomatic.

Comment: *"[They] were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should."*

Answer (score 1):

The expression uses [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) property of the OR operator. The right-hand side is only evaluated if the left-hand side is false. That way it's just another way to write conditional code.

Comment: Thank you very much!